# T-SQL MERGE statement with Identity INSERT

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Writing my first MERGE Statement and used the INSERT portion to update a table with an identity column

The end of my T-SQL returns the @@IDENTITY (or I could return SCOPE_IDENTITY()).

However if the UPDATE portion was triggered, the returned value must be null and throws an error on the client.

I "fixed" by doing SELECT ISNULL(@@IDENTITY, -99999) --A bogus value.

Is there a better way to return @@IDENTITY on INSERT but some other value on UPDATE?

Comment: You can use an [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to get any data from the rows (Note plural.), e.g. identity column values for newly inserted rows.  `OUTPUT` can be used with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `MERGE` and provides access to both before and after values in the case of `UPDATE`.  A tool well worth having in your pocket. [`@@IDENTITY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx) is almost always a bad thing, as the remarks in the documentation explain the effect of multiple rows, triggers, ... .

Comment: After I posted this I switched from Using @@IDENTITY to  SCOPE_IDENTITY() which I hope is better.     I will take a look at the OUTPUT Clause.

Answer (score 0):

I had to explain OUTPUT clauses earlier and this is what I did. I've added a a return value at the end so you can return the max Identity of this insert.

Here is an example of how to capture the max identity inserted by a merge.

```
--schema
CREATE TABLE #data
(
  id INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
         PRIMARY KEY
, Name VARCHAR(15) UNIQUE
, SomethingToUpdate INT NOT NULL
                        DEFAULT 1
)
--specimen data
INSERT  INTO #data
        ( Name )
VALUES  ( 'Andy' ),( 'Ben' ),( 'Charles' ),( 'Dave' ),( 'Elle' )
    --  ,( 'Zeb' ),( 'Xavier' ),( 'Yan' )


DECLARE @results TABLE
( id INT
, action nvarchar(10))

MERGE #data data
USING (
VALUES
    ( 'Zeb' ),
    ( 'Xavier' ),
    ( 'Yan' ),
    ( 'Dave' ),
    ('Ben')
) merger ( Name )
ON data.Name = merger.Name
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET data.SomethingToUpdate = data.SomethingToUpdate + 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT ( Name )
    VALUES ( merger.Name )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE
OUTPUT ISNULL(Inserted.id,Deleted.id), $action  INTO @results
;

DECLARE @returnValue NUMERIC(18,0)

SELECT @returnValue = MAX(id) FROM @results WHERE action = 'INSERT'

PRINT @returnValue
--RETURN @returnValue
```